# Ambari registration phase fails for SSL on EC2

Tags: apache, hadoop, ambari

I am trying to use Apache Ambari to configure a Hadoop cluster on EC2.

During the registration phase I get this error:

```
Command start time 2016-11-23 20:25:12
('Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_agent/main.py", line 312, in <module>
    main(heartbeat_stop_callback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_agent/main.py", line 248, in main
    stop_agent()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_agent/main.py", line 198, in stop_agent
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
INFO 2016-11-23 20:25:18,716 ExitHelper.py:53 - Performing cleanup before exiting...
INFO 2016-11-23 20:25:18,907 main.py:74 - loglevel=logging.INFO
INFO 2016-11-23 20:25:18,907 DataCleaner.py:39 - Data cleanup thread started
INFO 2016-11-23 20:25:18,908 DataCleaner.py:120 - Data cleanup started
INFO 2016-11-23 20:25:18,909 DataCleaner.py:122 - Data cleanup finished
INFO 2016-11-23 20:25:18,930 PingPortListener.py:50 - Ping port listener started on port: 8670
INFO 2016-11-23 20:25:18,931 main.py:289 - Connecting to Ambari server at https://IPADDRESS.us-west-2.compute.internal:8440 (172.31.37.172)
INFO 2016-11-23 20:25:18,931 NetUtil.py:59 - Connecting to https://IPADDRESS.us-west-2.compute.internal:8440/ca
ERROR 2016-11-23 20:25:18,983 NetUtil.py:77 - [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
ERROR 2016-11-23 20:25:18,983 NetUtil.py:78 - SSLError: Failed to connect. Please check openssl library versions. 
Refer to: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1022468 for more details.
WARNING 2016-11-23 20:25:18,983 NetUtil.py:105 - Server at https://IPADDRESS.us-west-2.compute.internal:8440 is not reachable, sleeping for 10 seconds...
', None)
('Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_agent/main.py", line 312, in <module>
    main(heartbeat_stop_callback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_agent/main.py", line 248, in main
    stop_agent()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_agent/main.py", line 198, in stop_agent
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
INFO 2016-11-23 20:25:18,716 ExitHelper.py:53 - Performing cleanup before exiting...
INFO 2016-11-23 20:25:18,907 main.py:74 - loglevel=logging.INFO
INFO 2016-11-23 20:25:18,907 DataCleaner.py:39 - Data cleanup thread started
INFO 2016-11-23 20:25:18,908 DataCleaner.py:120 - Data cleanup started
INFO 2016-11-23 20:25:18,909 DataCleaner.py:122 - Data cleanup finished
INFO 2016-11-23 20:25:18,930 PingPortListener.py:50 - Ping port listener started on port: 8670
INFO 2016-11-23 20:25:18,931 main.py:289 - Connecting to Ambari server at https://IPADDRESS.us-west-2.compute.internal:8440 (172.31.37.172)
INFO 2016-11-23 20:25:18,931 NetUtil.py:59 - Connecting to https://IPADDRESS.us-west-2.compute.internal:8440/ca
ERROR 2016-11-23 20:25:18,983 NetUtil.py:77 - [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
ERROR 2016-11-23 20:25:18,983 NetUtil.py:78 - SSLError: Failed to connect. Please check openssl library versions. 
Refer to: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1022468 for more details.
WARNING 2016-11-23 20:25:18,983 NetUtil.py:105 - Server at https://IPADDRESS.us-west-2.compute.internal:8440 is not reachable, sleeping for 10 seconds...
', None)


Connection to IPADDRESS.us-west-2.compute.internal closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=IPADDRESS.us-west-2.compute.internal, exitcode=0
Command end time 2016-11-23 20:25:21


Registering with the server...
Registration with the server failed.
```

I think it is something basic, but I was not able to solve.

The openssl version is 1.0.2g

Any advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a known issue related to JDK being used on the host machine for Ambari server.

The post [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/145/openssl-error-upon-host-registration.html) mentions that Oracle JDK should be used to get past this problem.

Answer (score 0):

in case this is not the JDK issue as mentioned [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/145/openssl-error-upon-host-registration.html), then there would be some issue with the version of the python being used for launching ambari-agent and ambari-server. Make sure that both are using same version i.e python 2.7 etc and restart them.

P.S After struggling hours when I ran into this issue, it was due to ambari-server running python2.6 and agent running in python2.7 for me.